# getting Duplicate entries in DB

Tags: android

I am parsing an xml and after parsing that xml i am storing the records in DB. I am using SQLite as DB. My data is in form of slideshows in xml. When i store that in DB for some slideshows i get duplicate entries. for example, if my xml contains 3 slides, in DB 6 are stored  with different item id's hence every slide is saved 2 times. this is what i am doing

```
ArrayList<SlideShowItem>slideItems=Utils.database.getSlideItemOfUrl(Constants.StoriesTable,tempSlideShow.getFullStoryUrl().substring(0, index - 1), type);

                            if (slideItems == null) {
                                Log.d("store in DB: ", " when SlideItems == null ");

                                Log.d("SlideShow Title:   ", tempSlideShow.getTitle());
                                Log.d("SlideShow pub Date:   ", tempSlideShow.getPubDate());
                                Utils.database.storeSlideItem(Constants.StoriesTable, myUrl, tempSlideShow.getSlideShow(), null);
                                //Utils.topStorySlidesArrayList = slideItems;

                            } else {
                                //Log.d("SlideShow Title:   ", tempSlideShow.getTitle());
                                Log.d("Already in DB ", " when SlideItems is not null ");
                                Utils.topStorySlidesArrayList = slideItems;

                            }
```

Please any help is apprecitaed. i think i am placing some check wrong. please help me in this regard.

Utils.database.storeSlideItem  contains this code:

```
public synchronized void storeSlideItem(String tableName, String url, ArrayList<SlideShowItem> list, String type) {

    System.out.println("size of the Array list:   " + list.size());

    String newType = null;
    if (type == null) {
        newType = "List";
    }else{
        newType = type;
    }       

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            SlideShowItem item = list.get(i);
            String itemUrl = url + i;// Unique URL for the DB;
            String imgString = null;
            Drawable drawable = item.getImage();
            if (item.getBody() != null) {
                item.setBody(item.getBody().replace('\'', '`'));
                // replace as it create syntax error for storing data
            }
            if (item.getSubTitle() != null) {
                item.setSubTitle(item.getSubTitle().replace('\'', '`'));
            }

            if (drawable != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                imgString = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
            }

            if (isOpen()) {
                myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tableName + "(" + column[1] + "," + column[2] + "," + column[3] + "," + column[4] + "," + column[6]
                        + "," + column[7] + ",type) VALUES('" + itemUrl + "','" + item.getSubTitle() + "','" + item.getBody() + "','"
                        + item.getImagePath() + "','" + item.getIndex() + "','" + imgString + "','" + newType + "Slide')");
                if (item.getBody() != null) {
                    item.setBody(item.getBody().replace('`', '\''));// " ' "
                    // replace as it create syntax error for storing data
                }
                if (item.getSubTitle() != null) {
                    item.setSubTitle(item.getSubTitle().replace('`', '\''));
                }

                if (tableName.equals(Constants.StoriesTable)) {
                    item.setItemId(getItemID(tableName, itemUrl));
                    Utils.hashListStoriesIds.put(itemUrl, item.getItemId());

                    if (imgString != null) {
                        Utils.hashListImages.put(item.getItemId(), new Boolean(true));
                    } else {
                        Utils.hashListImages.put(item.getItemId(), new Boolean(false));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Exception: storeSlideItem type " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        closeConnection();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code of your `Utils.database.storeSlideItem` method.

Comment: @THelper i Have provided that code too..now see if u can help.!!!

Comment: I noticed that you are first saving stuff to your database and then changing some of the item's properties? (setBody, SetSubTitle, SetItemId). Shouldn't you save to the db AFTER changing the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any unique ID field in your items? If so you can make that a primary key in the database schema, this will force all entries to be different or throw an exception when a duplicate is added so you can track down the problem.

Comment: Yes there is a primary key, which is itemID and this is generated at runtime on the basis of url of the slide.

Comment: Is the itemID generated when you save the slide or when you create it? Could you be loading the URL twice and hence creating double the number of slides. 
If you load the same URL several times will you get 3 different itemIDs or the same one 3 times? If you get 3 different ones you may need to add another method to generate them so they are the same for each URL. As you have a primary key on the DB your problem is almost certainly accidental duplication of slides.

Comment: Xup it's accidental as does not happen for every slideshow. However, itemId is allotted to a slide just before saving to DB and there is a separate method to do so.

Comment: That will be it, try Thread.dumpStack() in the method that generates the itemID to see when its being called, you may spot something out of place.
Could you also just use the URL directly, if the DB sees its already in then it can skip the saving?

Comment: xup...on the basis of url it is decided to save an item or not.